# How can I fix badly specified geographic coordinate system with units in arc-seconds?

Tags: gdal, proj, gdalwarp

Check out this [depth-to-rock soil data](ftp://dbftp.essc.psu.edu/pub/data/1996-0002/rockdepm.e00.gz).  It is linked from [here](http://www.soilinfo.psu.edu/index.cgi?soil_data&conus&data_cov&dtb&datasets&geo#arcgrid).  The spatial reference system is a latlon, but the units are arcseconds.  I could not reason out how to override the SRS even after staring at [this page in the Proj4 wiki](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms) for a while and trying to convert the origin coordinates using `cs2cs` with a `+towgs84` argument.

Here's the `gdalinfo` output for that file:

```
Driver: E00GRID/Arc/Info Export E00 GRID
Files: rockdepm.e00
Size is 6936, 2984
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["NAD27",
    DATUM["North_American_Datum_1927",
        SPHEROID["Clarke 1866",6378206.4,294.978698213898,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7008"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6267"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4267"]]
Origin = (-449100.000000000000000,177840.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (30.000000000000000,-30.000000000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -449100.000,  177840.000) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Lower Left  ( -449100.000,   88320.000) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Upper Right ( -241020.000,  177840.000) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Lower Right ( -241020.000,   88320.000) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Center      ( -345060.000,  133080.000) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Band 1 Block=6936x1 Type=Int32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.000 Max=191.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=191.000, Mean=123.286, StdDev=38.233
  NoData Value=-2147483647
```

Notice that the pixel size is 30 arcseconds.  If you divide a given set of coordinates by 3600 you get something that makes sense in degrees.

In the course of composing this question I have discovered that the data is available with other SRSs, but in case those are poorly defined as well I thought I would post anyhow.

Comment: You don't really need to reproject it, just georeference it again by resetting the origin and pixel sizes. Would gdal_edit.py work? http://www.gdal.org/gdal_edit.html

Comment: Sounds promising.  I would love to try it, but I don't see gdal_edit or gdal_edit.py in my $PATH with GDAL 1.9.2 installed.  Is that something extra in the source code that is not installed by default, perhaps?

Comment: Could be. I just downloaded gdal192.zip and the file's in gdal-1.9.2\swig\python\samples.

Comment: @mkennedy, if you want credit for this answer then write it up and I will do my part.  I found that the E00GRID driver does not support in-place edits, so I used `gdal_translate` to create a VRT wrapper and then edited that.

Comment: I think you did the actual work! I just pointed out the way. Why don't you write up your solution and accept it?